# Why does "Safari Web Content quit unexpectedly" occur often in macOS Sierra?

Tags: macos

"Safari Web Content quit unexpectedly" seems to occur very often after upgrading to macOS Sierra. Are there any solutions?

Comment: not just Sierra - El Capitan after Safari upgrade to 10.0.3